# Why does curl -o output contain sequences like "^[[38;5;250m", when "surf" output looks fine?

Tags: bash, curl

I want to output wttr.in in to a file with curl. The problem is that the output isn't how it would be when i just `surf wttr.in`.

What i did is:
`curl wttr.in -o ~/wt.tex` and `curl wttr.in -o ~/wt`

The output is like: <[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu8As.jpg)>

It should be https://wttr.in.

Comment: Those are ANSI escape codes, essentially HTML for terminals. If you `cat ~/wt` you'll see it formatted correctly. Do you want uncolored plain text instead?

Comment: How are you looking at the contents of those files?

Comment: Note that our rules require that where at all possible, questions be *self-contained* enough to be answerable (and helpful/understandable to other/future readers) even if all links therein break.  Also, note that StackOverflow's scope is limited to questions *unique to software development*; command line tool use is outside of it.

Comment: ...I tried to edit the title to make it more clear what the problem is (in a way that works regardless of the status of the contained links).

Comment: So the main idea is a little more advanced. I have a i3blcks module which reads out some stuff from wttr.in (that works fine). I also want to click on the module and it opens wttr.in with 'less -S', so i can scroll through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my self:
`less -r -f -L wt.tex`
-r controlls the binary characters
-f forces to open the the file with out asking.